# change default service preference for application/xml global

Tags: mime-types, kde-plasma, kde4, konqueror

**Background:**

KDE4 
global change application/xml (all users)

For application xml in "services preference order" the default
is that konqueror use "KHTML (khtml)" profile (see service preference order) on top in local provice file associations.

But where is this default stored on the system and where can I change it?

I do not want to change it for every user in .config oder .local (mimeapps.list). **I have to do this for all users.** I did not find this mimetype in any other global mimeapps.list.

**aim:**

Every users should have the "Embedded Advanced Text Editor (katepart)" as default on top for application/xml.